# Air Native Extension not recognizing default extension, so SWFs built with it do not start

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I'm building a native extension and when I try and run a SWF from an Flex Mobile app that is using this native extension it fails to load, even though the default package is available. It does not give me any errors. I can launch it in the simulator, and everything works fine.

When building the extension my directory structure is as follows (replacing the name of my company with ThirdParty)

```
build/
   ThirdParty.framework
   ThirdParty.swc
   default/
       library.swf (This is from a flex library project that is just a stub for the ANE)
   ios/
       library.swf (This is from a flex library project that connects with libThirdParty.a)
       libThirdParty.a
       ThirdParty.bundle
       platformoptions.xml
```

This is the command I run to build it:

```
adt -package -target ane ThirdParty.ane extension.xml -swc ThirdParty.swc -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions ios/platformoptions.xml ./ThirdParty.framework -C ios . -platform iPhone-x86 -platformoptions ios/platformoptions.xml ./ThirdParty.framework -C ios . -platform default -C default .
```

This is my extension.xml

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.8"> 
    <id>com.thirdparty.sdk</id> 
    <versionNumber>0.0.1</versionNumber> 
    <platforms>
        <platform name="iPhone-ARM"> 
            <applicationDeployment> 
                <nativeLibrary>libThirdPartyAirSDK.a</nativeLibrary> 
                <initializer>ThirdPartyExtensionInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>ThirdPartyExtensionFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
        <platform name="iPhone-x86"> 
            <applicationDeployment> 
                <nativeLibrary>libThirdPartyAirSDK.a</nativeLibrary> 
                <initializer>ThirdPartyExtensionInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>ThirdPartyExtensionFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
        <platform name="default">
            <applicationDeployment/>
        </platform>
    </platforms> 
</extension>
```

My platform options:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.8"> 
    <sdkVersion>6.1</sdkVersion>
    <linkerOptions> 
            <option>-framework ThirdParty</option> 
            <option>-liconv</option> 
    </linkerOptions>
    <packagedDependencies> 
        <packagedDependency>ThirdParty.framework</packagedDependency> 
    </packagedDependencies>
</platform>
```

Notes:

- I have downloaded and overlaid AirSDK 3.9 but if I use the 3.9 namespace it complains. (Even though it doesn't complain when I use the 3.9 application namespace)
- The ios extension works just fine, its getting the default extension to run that fails
- If I run a project using it in the AIR Device Simulator I get the folowing error

Error:

```
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

Not supported native extensions profile

Launch command details:  "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0/bin/adl" - runtime "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0/runtimes/air/mac" -profile extendedMobileDevice -screensize 640x920:640x960 -XscreenDPI 326 -XversionPlatform IOS -extdir "/Users/username/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui/ANEFiles/ThirdPartyGameApp/macosx/" /Users/username/src/github.com/thirdparty/ThirdPartyGameApp/bin-debug/ThirdPartyGameApp-app.xml /Users/username/src/github.com/thirdparty/ThirdPartyGameApp/bin-debug
```

Comment: But adl is the debug launcher not the compiler. So shouldn't it be launched with the same SDK that compiled it?